# How do I implement a lazy "reducing map" function?

Tags: recursion, clojure, dictionary, reduce, cons

I am trying to implement a "reducing map" function. That is, it should return a sequence consisting of the result of applying `f` to the first 2 items of `coll`, followed by the result of applying `f` to that result and the third item in `coll`, etc.

```
(def c [[0 0 0 0] [1 0 0 0] [0 1 0 0] [0 0 1 0] [0 0 0 1]])

(defn- sum-vector [v1 v2]
  (map + v1 v2))

(defn reduce-map [f coll & acc]
  (if (< (count coll) 2)
    (if (empty? acc) coll acc)
    (let [head (apply f (take 2 coll))
          tail (drop 2 coll)]
      (recur f (conj tail head) (conj acc head)))))
```

For example, calling this function like this:

```
(reduce-map sum-vector c)
```

should return:

```
[[1 0 0 0] [1 1 0 0] [1 1 1 0] [1 1 1 1]]
```

(Actually, it should probably return the first item unmodified as well, to better mimic `map`, but I can fix that later.)

Right, now, this is what it returns:

```
((1 1 1 1) (1 1 1 0) (1 1 0 0) (1 0 0 0))
```

**How do I "push" at the end of a(ny) seq?**

If I substitute `reduce-map` for `recur`, this is what it returns:

```
(((1 1 1 1) ((1 1 1 0) ((1 1 0 0) ((1 0 0 0))))))
```

**What is the difference between `recur` and true recursion in my code above?**

And, **is there a built-in, or better, or more idiomatic, way of implementing `reduce-map`?**

Finally, I'd like the output sequence to be lazy. Do I just wrap the whole thing in `lazy-seq`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This sounds a little bit like [`reductions`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/reductions).

As to "pushing" at the end of seq: in general seqs don't have an "end", cf. `(iterate inc 0)`.

As to "pushing" at the end of a list: lists are not designed for that. Use a vector. Seed your accumulator with `[]`, not `nil`.

As to `lazy-seq`: Use "true" recursion instead of `recur`. Here an example:

```
(defn integer-seq
  [start]
  (lazy-seq
    (cons start (integer-seq (inc start)))))
```

Comment: Well that was *fast*. Thanks!